# Simple stamped IF's in Polymer not working

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to build a simple component which will show a template based on a conditional.

If `user.isAdmin` is `true` then show the *Admin Area*, otherwise show the *Guest Area*.

For some reason none of the 2 template areas show up. What am I missing?

---

This is my component:

```
<dom-module id="custom-component">
  <!--DOM-->
  <template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!user.isAdmin}}">
      Guest Area
    </template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{user.isAdmin}}">
      Admin Area
    </template>

  </template>
  <!--Scripts-->
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-component',
      properties: {
        user: {"name":"Sample Name","isAdmin":true}
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Default values for properties may be specified in the properties object using the value field. The value may either be a primitive value, **or a function that returns a value (which should be used for initializing Objects and Arrays to avoid shared objects on instances).**

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="unsupported-message">
    <!--DOM-->
    <template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="{{!user.isAdmin}}">
        Guest Area
      </template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="{{user.isAdmin}}">
        Admin Area
      </template>

    </template>
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'unsupported-message',
        properties: {
          user: { // You'll have to declare your object properties this way
            type: Object,
            value: function() {
              return {
                "name": "Mr. Admin",
                "isAdmin": true
              };
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>

  </dom-module>
  <unsupported-message></unsupported-message>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - documentation could have been more explicit on this one in the data-binding sections